# How to use rasphone.exe to get vpn connection without always prompting for password

Tags: vb.net, vpn

I have an app that connects a Windows VPN (not OpenVPN) using the rasphone.exe interface. I can successfully establish the connection but It prompts for the password each time. Is there a way to get the interface to remember the password so that if the connection is lost the connection can automatically be re-established programatically? As a note when I start the process for rasphone.exe I'm getting exceptions when I try to pass more than 1 parameter to it. The only parameter I can successfully pass is the entry name, I can't add parameters like -d, -h, or -f.

Here is the code I have:

```
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Net.NetworkInformation

Public Class clsVPN

    Public Delegate Sub delPing()
    Public Delegate Sub delConnect()
    Public Delegate Sub delIdle()
    Public Delegate Sub delDisconnect()
    Public Delegate Sub delStatus(blnConnected As Boolean)

    Public Event Ping As delPing
    Public Event Con As delConnect
    Public Event Discon As delDisconnect
    Public Event Idle As delIdle
    Public Event StatusChanged As delStatus

    Public strRASPhone As String = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasphone.exe"
    Public strIPAddress As String = ""
    Public strVPNCon As String = ""

    Public blnConnected As Boolean = False

    Dim file As String = "C : \Users\Tom\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk\rasphone.pbk"


    Protected Sub OnStatusChanged(blnConnected As Boolean)

        RaiseEvent StatusChanged(blnConnected)

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnDisconnect()

        RaiseEvent Discon()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnPing()

        RaiseEvent Ping()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnIdle()

        RaiseEvent Idle()

    End Sub

    Protected Sub OnConnect()

        RaiseEvent Con()

    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Connected() As Boolean

        Get

            Return blnConnected

        End Get

    End Property


    Public Property ConName() As String

        Get

            Return strVPNCon

        End Get

        Set(strValue As String)

            strVPNCon = strValue

        End Set

    End Property

    Public Function Test() As Boolean

        Dim blnSucceed As Boolean = False

        OnPing()

        Dim p As New Ping()

        If p.Send(strIPAddress).Status = IPStatus.Success Then

            blnSucceed = True

        Else

            blnSucceed = False

        End If

        p = Nothing

        If blnSucceed <> blnConnected Then

            blnConnected = blnSucceed

            OnStatusChanged(blnConnected)

        End If

        OnIdle()

        Return blnSucceed

    End Function

    Public Function Connect() As Boolean

        Dim blnSucceed As Boolean = False
        Dim optionstr As String = "-f " & file & " -d "

        OnConnect()

        'MessageBox.Show("strVPNCon = " )

        'Process.Start(strRASPhone, Convert.ToString(" -f ") & file & Convert.ToString(" -d ") _
        ' & strVPNCon)
        optionstr = ""

        Dim wait As Boolean = True

        ProcessExec(strRASPhone, optionstr & strVPNCon, wait)

        Application.DoEvents()

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)

        Application.DoEvents()

        blnSucceed = True

        OnIdle()

        Return blnSucceed

    End Function

    Public Function Disconnect() As Boolean

        Dim blnSucceed As Boolean = False
        Dim optionstr As String = "-h "

        OnDisconnect()

        optionstr = ""

        Dim wait As Boolean = True

        ProcessExec(strRASPhone, optionstr & strVPNCon, wait)

        Application.DoEvents()

        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(8000)

        Application.DoEvents()

        blnSucceed = True

        OnIdle()

        Return blnSucceed

    End Function

    Public Function CheckConnection() As Boolean

        Dim niVPN As NetworkInterface() =
         NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces

        Dim blnExist As Boolean =
         niVPN.AsEnumerable().Any(Function(x) x.Name = ConName)

        If blnExist Then

            'MessageBox.Show("VPN Exists")

        Else

            ' MessageBox.Show("VPN Does Not Exist")

        End If
        Return blnExist

    End Function

    Public Sub ProcessExec(processarg As String, param As String, wait As Boolean)

        ' Start the child process.
        Dim p As New ProcessStartInfo
        ' Redirect the output stream of the child process.
        p.FileName = processarg
        p.Arguments = param
        p.UseShellExecute = True
        p.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
        Dim proc As Process = Process.Start(p)
        ' Do Not wait for the child process to exit before
        ' reading to the end of its redirected stream.
        If wait = True Then
            proc.WaitForExit()
        End If

    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this was asked more than one year before.

I suppose that the described problem is not caused of the Visual Basic code. The problem may be caused from the file `rasphone.pbk`. It is generally contained in

> `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`

This file can be read with a text editor. There exist an option `PreviewUserPw` after `[YOURVPNNAME]`. The value `1` generates a prompting before dialing in.

Changing of this line to

```
PreviewUserPw=0
```

will help.